# Menu colapsado após seleção

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

Estou com dúvidas no menu colapse do bootstrap 4.1, quando o layout está em tela menor e colapsado, após selecionar uma opção ele não volta a colapsar, alguém sabe como fazer para resolver isso? Agradeço a ajuda!

```html
<!-- Carrega Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Carrega Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">



<body>

  <!-- Início Menu NAVBAR -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="img/header/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="d-none d-md-inline-block">
        <img src="img/header/logo-mini.png" alt="Logo-mini" class="d-md-none"></a>
      <div class="d-lg-none">
        <!-- Início Botão Menu Colapsado -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Fim Botão Menu Colapsado -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
          </li>
          <span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Em breve">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Loja Virtual</a>
            </li>
          </span>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contato">Contato</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Início redes sociais -->
        <span class="navbar-text">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden-"true"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden-"true"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden-"true"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden-"true"></i></a>
        </span>
        <!-- Fim redes sociais -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Fim Menu NAVBAR -->
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Amigo, não consegui reproduzir o problema que relatou. Faça novos testes para verificar se não é alguma coisa com o seu navegador por exemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve colocar um destino real aos links. Ao colocar `href="#"` você não sai da página e o menu nao recolhe.